# Running a single Mocha test not working with IntelliJ and Typescript

Tags: intellij-idea, mocha.js

I installed the NodeJS plugin for IntelliJ and running all mocha tests works.

When I try to run a single suite, Mocha generates a config for me like the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha \
--timeout 15000 \
--compilers ts:ts-node/register \
--ui bdd \
--reporter "/Users/Bersling/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2017.1/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js" \
/Users/Bersling/Desktop/IT-Projects/typescript-mongo-express-angular-node-seed/backend/src/router/endpoints/login-router.test.ts \
--grep "LoginRouter "
```

However, that doesn't work for me. I get the errors on tests that should work fine. Here's part of the logs.

```
error:  Error: Internal Server Error
    at Test.Request.callback (/Users/Bersling/Desktop/IT-Projects/typescript-mongo-express-angular-node-seed/backend/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:626:17)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/Bersling/Desktop/IT-Projects/typescript-mongo-express-angular-node-seed/backend/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:795:18)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
(node:90972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): AssertionError: false == true
Error: Unknown authentication strategy "local"
    at attempt (/Users/Bersling/Desktop/IT-Projects/typescript-mongo-express-angular-node-seed/backend/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:173:37)
```

What would work is the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha \
--timeout 15000 \
--compilers ts:ts-node/register \
--ui bdd \
--reporter "/Users/Bersling/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2017.1/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js" \
**/*.test.ts \
--grep "LoginRouter "
```

Like this the test runs fine.

Does anyone know how I could get this to run?

Answer (score 0):

Today I got the same error.
Try reinstalling mocha to another version then return previous version.
This works for me.